# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method inside the select section

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I need to `AddYears(2)` in the `select new ShowRequestsModel`. how can I do this? It throws an exception

```
var requests = (from req in db.PartRequests
                join info in db.UsersInfos on req.UserId equals info.aspnet_UserId
                join prodName in db.Products on req.ProductId equals prodName.Id
                join partRequestStatus in db.PartRequestStatus on req.PartRequestStatusId equals partRequestStatus.Id           
                select new ShowRequestsModel
                {                                                                                                                
                    WarantyExpirationDate = req.PurchasedDate.AddYears(2),
                    IsWarantyExpired = false
                })
                .Sort(sortField, sortBy);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `DbFunctions` class (`System.Data.Entity`), especially its
`AddYears()` method

```
var requests = (from req in db.PartRequests
            join info in db.UsersInfos on req.UserId equals info.aspnet_UserId
            join prodName in db.Products on req.ProductId equals prodName.Id
            join partRequestStatus in db.PartRequestStatus on req.PartRequestStatusId equals partRequestStatus.Id           
            select new ShowRequestsModel
            {                                                                                                                
                WarantyExpirationDate = DbFunctions.AddYears(req.PurchasedDate, 2),
                IsWarantyExpired = false
            })
            .Sort(sortField, sortBy);
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.addyears(v=vs.113).aspx